# Is it possible to load/import all scripts from folder in playframework?

Tags: playframework

Namely i want to do this kind of stuff:  `#{script 'tests/*.js'/}`. Do i have to write custom tag or there are some workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Play 2.0 all scripts included in public/assets will be parsed by Google Closure.

For Play 1.2.X, you should use local build scripts such as the one included in HTML5Boilerplate. A quick ant task, compresses, minifies and will join diffents scripts together. You could simply include the result file.

Comment: +1 good answer. Nice to see Play 2.0 starting to show itself in answers to question. Be cautious though, Play2.0 is liable to change heavily before it gets to alpha/beta phase.